# Sharepoint 2013 Online Site Collection Backup-Restore using CSOM

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, site-collection, backup, restore

I have created one site collection on SharePoint Online.

Now I want to make another site collection with the same content.

So can anyone explain me how to go about backup and restore of site collection in SharePoint Online (Office 365)? Using **CSOM**

Comment: Use can use saveAsTenplate option

Comment: i am trying take backup using CSOM, "save as Template"  not avaliable in CSOM

Comment: See my answer now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Save your site as template manually. Then find the template guid id.

[image]

Now create your site using CSOM. See more [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.online.sharepoint.tenantadministration.tenant.createsite.aspx)

```
internal void CreateSite(String targetUrl, String title, String owner, String siteTemplate)
{
    var ctx = new ClientContextWrapper(targetUrl);
    var tenant = new Tenant(ctx);

    //Create new site
    var newsite = new SiteCreationProperties()
    {
        Url = targetUrl,
        Owner = owner,
        Template = siteTemplate,
        Title = title,
        StorageMaximumLevel = 1000,
        StorageWarningLevel = 500,
        TimeZoneId = 7,
        UserCodeMaximumLevel = 7,
        UserCodeWarningLevel = 1,
    };

    var spoOperation = tenant.CreateSite(newsite);

    ctx.Load(spoOperation);
    ctx.ExecuteQuery();

    while (!spoOperation.IsComplete)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
        ctx.Load(spoOperation);
        ctx.ExecuteQuery();
        Console.WriteLine("Site creation status: " + (spoOperation.IsComplete ? "waiting" : "complete"));
    }
}
```

Place your custom template's guid in `siteTemplate`

Comment: My SharePoint Online doesn't have any option like this "ProjectSiteTemplate" in custom tab  and unable to find save site as template option in office 365

Comment: Did you save your site as template? If so, then what is the name? It's just the name of your template what you have provided

Comment: my sharepoint online site dosen't show option "save site as template"

Comment: Go to the link your-site-url/_layouts/savetmpl.aspx

Comment: Hello Atish ,my site is "Publishing Site", so i am unable to "save site as template". when i am go through  this link your-site-url/_layouts/savetmpl.aspx  , getting error

Comment: Hi @I-touch. It does not matter what ever the site is! Enable save as template option from designer. http://community.bamboosolutions.com/blogs/sharepoint-2013/archive/2014/05/12/how-to-enable-save-site-as-template-in-sharepoint-2013-using-sharepoint-designer.aspx

Comment: i have made change in SharePoint designer "SaveSiteAsTemplate"  to true , still not able to show these option in site action,                                         but now i am able to save site as template through URL your-site-url/_layouts/savetmpl.aspx

Comment: Ok ..... Now find the template guid id and apply CSOM code.

Comment: m not yet tested above code , m working on that , as per u saying using above code , i can create new site using existing site template ,                   is that true?

Comment: Hi @Atish , trying to use above CSOM code in PowerShell ..                          so is that possible to use above code in Powershell .