# Sharepoint 2013 Online Site Collection Backup-Restore using CSOM in Powershell

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, backup, restore, csom

i have created Publishing site collection on SharePoint Online.

Now i am trying to create new Publishing Site Collection with same Contents

So can anyone explain me how to go about **backup and restore** of site collection in **SharePoint Online** (Office 365)? Using **CSOM** in **PowerShell**

Comment: I tried this in the past also. But I only found a solution to backup lists with the export function. But that contains a 5 MB limit. I doesn't found another solution for this.

Comment: I can give you the same solution as like http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/158995/21421 using powershell

Comment: worth reading https://community.office365.com/en-us/f/156/t/271344

Comment: hi @Sascha will u please give me link ,  that shows that list export limit is 5MB

Comment: Try to export more as 5 MB, then you get an error that this limit will be exceed :).